# How to run an Act framework application without using intelliJ IDEA

Tags: actframework

I just started with Act Framework but I do not want to use intelliJ IDEA. How do I run my app on windows and on linux using CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Act in development mode using

`mvn clean compile exec:exec`

and in the production mode with

`mvn clean package
cd target/dist
unzip *
./start`

I got this from a [link](https://github.com/actframework/act-demo-apps/tree/master/helloworld) in the gitter channel for Act

Comment: To make it able to run Act app in above way, one must create act application following the demo project: https://github.com/actframework/act-demo-apps or using the act starter kit: https://github.com/actframework/act-starter-kit